# Passing message to client without using FAULT CONTRACT

Tags: wcf

Recently I have been asked in an interview as how to pass exception detail to client

without using FAULT CONTRACT.

I was not able to answer.

But I need to know it. So looking forward to hear about the same.

Answer (score 0):

I guess they asked you for this:

```
<behavior>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ExceptionBehavior">
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailsInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behavior>
```

Comment: Fine.. apart from this any other way of sending the exception to client?

Comment: Only custom like try / catch and send exception in valid response.